# Membership.IsApproved value not saved

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, forms-authentication

I have this code:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
if (user != null) 
    user.IsApproved = false;
```

The call to `user.IsApproved` above does set the `IsApproved` flag to `false` but when I subsequently do:

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
```

and check the `IsApproved` flag the value is `true`!

What's wrong?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to save the change, otherwise you're just setting it to false for the current object. You can use `Membership.UpdateUser` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx).

```
MembershipUser user = Membership.GetUser(model.UserName);
if (user != null){
    user.IsApproved = false;
    Membership.UpdateUser(user);
}
```

Answer (score 5):

Looking on msdn doing [`user.IsApproved = false`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membershipuser.isapproved.aspx) does not update the data store.

If you wish to persist the change you need to call [`UpdateUser(user)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.updateuser.aspx)